# Shortest path in a tree

Tags: data-structures, trees, shortest-path

Is it correct to talk about shortest path in a tree, isn't a tree has only single path between any two nodes ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)#Tree - "Any two vertices in G can be connected by a unique simple path."

Comment: And hence that path is the shortest path between them as well